# Close a specific Chrome tab in Ubuntu/Linux using terminal command

Tags: linux, shell, google-chrome, terminal

Is there a way to close a specific Chrome tab with a terminal command? I tried below commands:

1. `kill -9 <pid of Chrome tab>`: Instead of closing a tab, it kills the tab ("He's dead Jim" message appears and tab remains)
2. `killall chrome`: Closes all Chrome browsers open

Comment: No, there's no signal or commandline switch to close an individual tab.

Comment: You would need to use https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix with the extension https://github.com/smblott-github/chromi to do that.

Answer (score -2):

## You can close a specific crome tab on follow way by terminal:

Change the active tab to the next right tab:

```
xdotool windowactivate --sync <window> key Ctrl + Tab
```

Change the active tab to the next left tab:

```
xdotool windowactivate --sync <window> Ctrl  + Shift + Tab
```

Close the active browser tab by:

```
xdotool windowactivate --sync <window> Ctrl + w
```

**Remark:**
The Strg key on german keyboards is usually labelled Ctrl or Control on english keyboairds.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: The key which is labeled `Strg` on German keyboards is usually labelled `Ctrl` or `Control` internationally.

Comment: @tripleee, Strg are changed now to Ctrl.